# How can I call a protobuf object's function in GDB?

Tags: gdb, protocol-buffers

The protobuf definition is:

```
message AttackUserInfo
{
    required string name = 1;
    repeated uint32 skill_ids = 2;
}
```

Now, there a protobuf object **attackUserInfo**.
I want to clear the skill_ids.What should I do in gdb?
I have called the function Clear_skill_ids().But It isn't effect.

```
gdb> call attackUserInfo.Clear_skill_ids()      //It cored.
```

Comment: Normally the method would be called `clear_skill_ids()` (lower-case). Is that your problem? If not, you'll need to provide more details about what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Thx..It's lower-case.Actually when I call `attackUserInfo.clear_skill_ids()`,   gdb's  prompt message is `Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined`, but when I call `attackUserInfo.skill_ids_size()`, it works. I just want to clear `skill_ids`..

Answer (score 0):

What is "It" in "It cored"? Did the program under GDB get `SIGSEGV`, or did GDB itself dump core?

If the latter, it's a bug in GDB. You should upgrade it to the latest version, and if that doesn't help, file a bug against GDB with repro instructions.

Comment: Thx, In fact , `It cored` when I `set attackUserInfo.skill_ids_.current_size_=0`.I get it wrong..Actually when I call attackUserInfo.clear_skill_ids(), gdb's prompt message is `Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined`.

Comment: @mjammer What is "it" in your two messages? It is *extremely* unhelpful to say "it" when you have two possible subjects. Is it GDB that core dumps? Is it the target program?